# Installed WDK Version from windows command line

Tags: windows, command, containers, wdk, windows-container

How do I find out the installed WDK version on my windows machine via the windows command line? I can find it through Visual studio and "Control Panel -> Installed Softwares" on my local machine but I'm trying to check this on a container and only have access to the windows command line and cannot confirm if there is a wdk installed on the container.

Comment: That seems backward. Usually, when you have a requirement, you expect clients to meet those requirements. What is the particular problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm unable to compile something in windows containers using VS 2019 which requires a wdk installation, I would like to verify that the wdk being used in the dockerfile is actually installed in the docker image

Comment: The fact that the WDK is installed isn't sufficient to use it. You'll also need to set up your environment so that the individual pieces are discoverable by whatever tooling needs it. I'm sure you can use the [Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal) API to verify existence of an installed package, if that is what you wish to do.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the environment that I need to setup to use the WDK with Visual Studio? I keep getting the following error when trying to compile a VS Solution file.

Comment: "  error MSB8020: The build tools for WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'Windows ApplicationForDrivers10.0') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 build tools, please install WindowsApplicationForDrivers10.0 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". "

Comment: VS Command used for compilation :
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" &&  msbuild myproject.sln /m /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration="Release"

Comment: The WDK comes with [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237820/discussion-between-jose-and-iinspectable).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, you still need the answer, but I have a crunch.

The easiest way to get latest installed version, would be read file

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.Default.props`

which is used by `MSBuild` during the build. This file has following content:

```xml
  <!-- some content before... -->

  <PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Current KitOS property -->
    <CurrentKitOS>winv10.0</CurrentKitOS>

    <!-- Latest Target Version property -->
    <LatestTargetVersion>Windows10</LatestTargetVersion>

    <!-- Older TargetPlatformVersion properties -->
    <TargetPlatformVersion_TH1>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformVersion_TH1>
    <TargetPlatformVersion_TH2>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformVersion_TH2>
    <TargetPlatformVersion_RS1>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformVersion_RS1>
    <TargetPlatformVersion_RS2>10.0.15063.0</TargetPlatformVersion_RS2>
    <TargetPlatformVersion_RS3>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformVersion_RS3>
    <TargetPlatformVersion_RS4>10.0.17134.0</TargetPlatformVersion_RS4>
    <TargetPlatformVersion_RS5>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion_RS5>
    <TargetPlatformVersion_19H1>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion_19H1>

    <TargetVersion Condition="'$(TargetVersion)' == ''">$(LatestTargetVersion)</TargetVersion>

    <LatestTargetPlatformVersion>$([Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetLatestSDKTargetPlatformVersion('Windows', '10.0'))</LatestTargetPlatformVersion>
    <LatestWdkPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</LatestWdkPlatformVersion>
    <LatestTargetPlatformVersion Condition="'$(LatestTargetPlatformVersion)' != '' and '$(LatestTargetPlatformVersion)' &gt; '$(LatestWdkPlatformVersion)'">$(LatestWdkPlatformVersion)</LatestTargetPlatformVersion>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion Condition="'$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)' == ''">$(LatestTargetPlatformVersion)</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <OverrideCfgV1 Condition="'$(OverrideCfgV1)' == '' and '$(WindowsTargetPlatformVersion)' &lt;= '10.0.14250.0'">true</OverrideCfgV1>
    <MatchingSdkPresent Condition="Exists('$(WDKContentRoot)\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\UAP.props')">true</MatchingSdkPresent>
    <MatchingWdkPresent Condition="Exists('$(WDKContentRoot)\Include\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\km\ntddk.h')">true</MatchingWdkPresent>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- some content after... -->
```

You could read value of `<LatestTargetVersion>` tag to get the least installed version of WDK. And it is actually the only one thing need, because by default MSBuild will take the latest WDK, until you override `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` property to select particular SDK+WDK pair,

Even if it is not [compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) with installed Visual Studio version!

So for proper build you readlly should override `WindowsTargetPlatformVersion` property during `MSBuild` call.

The easiest way to get all installed WDK version is to read content of e.g.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include`

Here is the `DIR` output

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        19.11.2022     11:34                10.0.17763.0
d-----        19.11.2022     11:25                10.0.18362.0
d-----        19.11.2022     11:25                wdf
```

As you can notice, WDK has version folder for each version SDK/WDK.